# Calling a glut function exits the program

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glut, glew

I'm attempting to use OpenGL with Qt (relatively new to both of them), but whenever the program encounters a glut function like `gluSolidCube` or similar, it simply exits. I'm sure I'm missing something very basic here, but I have tried putting the dll files everywhere within the solution directories, to no avail. Calling `initGlew` also does not make a difference.

Any help would be much appreciated.

NB: Other GL functions that do not require glut work perfectly fine.

Comment: Did you have QT += opengl at your .pro?

Comment: If you are referring to whether I have the OpenGL module included, yes I do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GLUT is not part of OpenGL. It's a rather simple framework library and needs to be initialized by `glutInit(&argc, argv);` in the `main` entry point function. Without initialization GLUT functions will call `exit` when invoked, thus terminating your program.

Technically I discourage using GLUT for doing something as simple as drawing a cube. The teapot maybe, but that's about it. Otherwise I say, don't use GLUT at all.